# UEFI multi-factor authentication on admin password?

Tags: boot, security, passwords, uefi, secure-boot

Many UEFI vendors offer boot and Admin passwords for a local machine.

For a normal cold boot or reset, I would like the UEFI system to simply pick the properly signed bootloader and proceed.

Having a 'well known' admin password for getting into the UEFI is something I would prefer **NOT** move forward with.

However in the ideal case if someone gets physical control of a device (and has used social engineering to obtain the 'well known' password for UEFI admin access) I would prefer to make it extra difficult for the equipment to be **re-purposed**.  It would be computationally challenging (but not theoretically impossible :-( ) for a compromised system to be useful for acquiring data stored on the system (encrypted drives). But it is possible that having the UEFI admin password would allow an 'imposter' to load a newly provisioned and signed bootloader.

One idea is using something like RSA SecureID or having the UEFI spit out a one time code that has to be checked against another server.

I have only seen UEFI vendor offerings that have essentially a 'plaintext' password for access to the firmware IF at the machine. **Has anyone encountered a UEFI firmware vendor that has gone beyond the normal "enter the password?"**

Comment: Would be meaningless physical access means you can reset the firmware by pulling the battery and replace the HDD.  You can't stop the usage of the hardware but can stop the data from being accessed

Comment: Yeah, the point was just to 'make it extra difficult' to repurpose the hardware. If the firmware can (and it can) be reflashed via JTAG that is going to bypass most of the protection.  The data is safe from 'known' attempts at access, but the hardware is still 'usable' (including the HDD). Also, having the second-factor authentication keeps the 'honest criminals' out of trying to add another UEFI key and change the boot order or even disabling UEFI. Physical security in this case is important, but a compromised system could do lots of 'sniffing' around.

Comment: There is no UEFI firmware on the market that uses 2-factor authentication.  I don't even believe the UEFI specification even supports it.

Comment: From the UEFI 2.4 Spec Section 32.1 "This is called multi-factor authentication." <snip> "The user identity manager is the optional UEFI driver which manages the process of determining the user’s identity and storing information about the user." <snip> In theory what I am looking for CAN be produced. I was hoping that it would already exist.  [link](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/2_4_Errata_B.pdf)